# Is Poisson formula valid for the weak solution of Laplacian?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

In the book "Regularity Theory for Elliptic PDE", here is a theorem as follows

> Theorem(Harnack's inequality). Assume $ u\in H^1(B_1) $ is a non-negative, is the weak solution for the laplace equation $ \Delta{u}=0\text{ in }B_1 $ where $ B_1 $ is the ball with center $ 0 $ and radius $ 1 $. Then the infimum and the supermum of $ u $ are comparable in $ B_{1/2} $. That is, there exists $ C $ depending only on $ n $, such that
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \sup_{B_{1/2}}u\leq C\inf_{B_{1/2}}u.
> \end{eqnarray}

The proof of this theorem in this book is by using Poisson kernel representation as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
u(x)=C_n\int_{\partial B_{1}}\frac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^n}u(y)dS(y),(*)
\end{eqnarray}
where $ C_n $ is a constant depending only on $ n $. I know that the proof of the final result is trivial by this representation formula. However I doubt the correctness of this Poisson kernel representation. By using the Weyl Lemma, I see that $ u\in C^{\infty}(B_1) $, but on $ \partial B_1 $, I cannot get that $ u(x)|_{\partial B_1} $ is continuous. Therefore, my question is the formula (*) correct for the weak solution $ u $ and how to derive this formula? Moreover, I know that if we use the Poisson integration on $ \partial B_{3/4} $, we can also have the Harnack inequality, but I still want to know if we can use the Poisson integration on $ \partial B_{1} $

Comment: Every weak solution of $\Delta u = 0$ is (equal a.e. to a) strong solution. Regarding the boundary values, if $u \in H^1(B_1)$, then $u$ has boundary trace in $H^{1/2}(\partial B_1)$ and of course the Poisson representation works as expected; [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator) may be a good entry point to the literature.

Comment: @Mateusz Kwaśnicki I know that $ u $ has boundary trace in $ H^{1/2}(\partial B_1) $, but I still cannot know why the Poisson representation works as expected by this trace fact.

Comment: If you're familiar with the trace operator, then I think this is straightforward: the formula holds for all harmonic $u \in C^\infty(\overline B_1)$, and so it extends to harmonic $u \in H^1(B_1)$ by continuity.

Comment: @Mateusz Kwaśnicki, in your point of view, I need to construct a sequence of $ u_m $ such that $ \Delta u_m=0 $, $ u\in C^{\infty}(\bar{B}_1) $ and $ u_m\rightarrow u $ strongly in $ H^1(B_1) $. However I can not get such $ u_m $, can you give me more details?

Comment: In this case you can simply take $u_m(x) = u((1+\tfrac1n)x)$, I suppose?

Comment: @Mateusz Kwaśnicki, thank you very much, but maybe $ u_m(x)=u(x/(1+1/m)) $.

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry.